# clarify options in linux for me i cant grasp the difference between - and --?

Tags: linux

Sometimes we are using a double hyphen with `a = ""` (ie `ls --hide=desktop` as the agument) and sometimes a single one followed by a space (ie `find . -type f`).
What is the difference between the two options?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between the 3 option syntax for commands in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896774/difference-between-the-3-option-syntax-for-commands-in-bash)

Comment: The thing to realize is that `-` or `--` doesn't mean anything to the OS or shell. It's just whatever the individual program chooses to read into it

Answer (score 1):

So a "-" would be used when a single char is needed such as "h" or "s". But a double hyphen is needed when giving a longer string. Some commands just go against this rule completely, as stated by psusi. 

In the case of "find" you can see that it tries to go along with the format by having "-type" followed by a single char. All in all, the answer is, "It depends."

---

---

## As stated in [this serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/387935/whats-the-difference-betwen-the-single-dash-and-double-dash-flags-on-shell-comm):

**Answer by [psusi](https://serverfault.com/users/84646/psusi):**

> A single hyphen can be followed by multiple single-character flags. A double hyphen prefixes a single, multicharacter option.

**Answer by [ssice](https://serverfault.com/users/120669/ssice):**

> If there was a "lisa" argument for ls, there would probably have a different meaning to type ls -lisa than ls --lisa. The former are the l, i, s, and a parameters, not the word.
>   There are also programs that don't obey this convention. Most notably for my sight, dd and gcc.

Comment: -name is not a single character